# What do I need to install to run Drush make?

Tags: drush

I want to make a site using a drush make command.I have already Drush installed on my server.
When I try to run this command: `drush make --prepare-install martplug-build.make mart plug` I receive this message: `The drush command 'make martplug-build.make martplug' could not be found.`

Should I also install Drush Make? If so how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Drush-4:

```
drush dl drush_make
```

Drush will put drush_make in the correct location (the .drush folder).

If you are using Drush-5, Drush make is included.

Answer (score 3):

Did you have a look at the [INSTALL.txt file](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush_make.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/INSTALL.txt). The easiest is to put it inside .drush folder